# Update database from changes of datagridview

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I get this error:

> The parameterized query '(@SupplierName nvarchar(50),@CostPrice nvarchar(50))UPDATE CostP' expects the parameter '@SupplierName', which was not supplied.

What is the problem here?

```
con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=tcp:SHEN-PC,49172\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LSEStock;Integrated Security=True";
con.Open();

String updateData = "UPDATE CostPrice SET SupplierName = @SupplierName, CostPrice = @CostPrice WHERE PartsID = '" +textBox1.Text+"'";
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(updateData, con);

update.Parameters.Add("@SupplierName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "SupplierName");
update.Parameters.Add("@CostPrice", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "CostPrice");

update.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Hi there! Distil your question into a more relevant piece of code and clearly marked issue. As it stands, it's not well formatted, it's a bit long, and frankly - you state the question last, after that wall of code. =)

Comment: sorry for that, but I really need help there, I can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with how you are setting the value - which is what I think is causing your error message.

Try this:

```
update.Parameters.Add("@SupplierName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "SupplierName";
```

There's an alternative to this on the MSDN page I link to below, which may also help.

MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5xwx8sc(v=vs.80).aspx